Intermittent Error On SQLServer Hourly Database Backup Maintenance Plan
Some of our SQLServer machines' hourly maintenance plan with Back Up Database Tasks are failing intermittently, around once or twice per week. The next hourly execution runs without any issue.  Each failure happened to a different machine.
SQLServer Agent logs shows:
Failed to acquire connection "Local server connection". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.
Could not load file or assembly " System.EnterpriseServices.wrapper.dll" or one of it's dependencies. Access denied.
Maintenance plan connects to SQLServer using windows authentication under the SQLServer Agent account. I have checked that the account have run and execute permission on the dll under "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"

Is this standalone server or a cluster or an availability group (basic / standard)? Please edit your original post to add more details about your configuration including SQL server version etc.
